# Best way to build a program that integrates with gmail

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am wanting to make some sort of program that can track all of my different packages for me. for example every time I buy something online the company will send a tracking number. I want to build a parser that can detect these tracking numbers and let me know when my packages will arrive.

I already know how to build the parser and such however I want to know the best way to access my email via nodejs. I would like a function to be called every time I receive an email however I am not sure how to implement this.

I saw gmail.js which looks promising but it seems like it is only a client-side app that is meant to be run within a web extension. Is there a way it could use google oauth or something like that to trigger a function within node?

Comment: Have you seen [Gmail API documentation for Node.js](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)?

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I have not thanks for pointing it out. however I can't seem to find a way to see received emails. Unless I use the sync mail client function. thanks for pointing it out need to look into it more.